# Replace youtube link with embed and leave other text unharmed

Tags: php, oop, replace

I'm trying to turn youtube links into embed iframes, to play the videos. However, my current code is replacing the entire sentence with the embed code. What I want to do is to just convert the youtube link to an embed code, and leave the rest of the text unharmed.

Example: `This is a youtube link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T-8XurAKMkU and some text after.`

Turned into: `This is a youtube link: <embed> and some text after.`

My current code:

```
$testing = "This is a youtube link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T-8XurAKMkU and some text after.";
echo $core->convertyoutube($testing);
```

And the function:

```
public function convertyoutube($link) {

        if (strpos($link, 'youtube.com/watch?v=') == true) {

            $url = $link;
            parse_str(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $youtube_array);
            $videoid = $youtube_array['v']; 

            $embed = "<iframe width='420' height='315' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/".$videoid."'></iframe>"; // what it should create with the extracted code
            return $embed;

        }


    }
```

Comment: You are just returning `$embed`, what happened to `$link` ? You will need to concenate it (.).

Comment: I store it in $url which I later on use in parse_str.

Comment: Unfortunately, not making any difference.

Comment: You could try this:
`parse_str(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $youtube_array);`
`preg_match("/[^\s]*/", $youtube_array['v'], $matches);`
`$videoid = $matches[0];`

Comment: Still only gives the embed video.

Comment: Yes, http://pastebin.com/302SeWmj

Comment: Mistook you for the other guy. My apologies. http://pastebin.com/YaLz53Hr Still only shows the embed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well You are returning only embed code:

```
return $embed;
```

You need to replace only youtube part:

```
public function convertyoutube($link) {
    $position = strpos($link, 'youtube.com/watch?v=');
    if ($position !== false) {

        $chunks = explode(' ', $link);
        foreach ($chunks as &$chunk) {
            $isYoutubeLink = strpos($chunk, 'youtube.com/watch?v=');
            if ($isYoutubeLink !== false) {
                $url = $chunk;
                parse_str(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $youtube_array);
                $videoid = $youtube_array['v']; 

                $chunk = "<iframe width='420' height='315' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/".$videoid."'></iframe>"; // what it should create with the extracted code
            }
        }
        return implode(' ', $chunks);
    }
}
```

It works with multiple links in sentence. I guess there is "better" way with using regexp, however I am not very good at regexp and don't like to use it where it is not mandatory.

Comment: Perfect! That's a good way of doing it without regexp indeed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could actually do this all with a single regex.

```
echo preg_replace('/https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtube\.com\/watch\?v=(.+?)(?:&|\s|$)/', 
               '<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/$1"></iframe>', 
               'This is a youtube link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T-8XurAKMkU and some text after.');
```

Output:

```
This is a youtube link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T-8XurAKMkU and some text after.
```

Regex101 Demo: https://regex101.com/r/cT2mW1/2

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm not very experienced with regex. Will try to remember it for future use!

Comment: The regex101 demo gives a break down on the side of everything being used. If you have a particular question about it please ask.

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if you convert the links at the front-end view with javascript to avoid a excess loading of server. But it's your choise.

Single youtube video has different links like these: 

1) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lfKON5AMvTM

2) https://youtu.be/lfKON5AMvTM

For this reason you should write your codes like this to catch every type of youtube links:

```
public function convertYouTube($content) {
    $content = preg_replace("/http(s)?:\/\/youtu\.be\/([^\40\t\r\n\<]+)/i", '<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/$2"></iframe>', $content);

    $content = preg_replace("/http(s)?:\/\/(w{3}\.)?youtube\.com\/watch\/?\?v=([^\40\t\r\n\<]+)/i", '<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/$3"></iframe>', $content);

    return $content;
}
```